# InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException trying to find using JPA query with Enum value

Tags: java, jpa, enums

Enum def -

```
public enum someAccountType {
    ACCOUNT_NUMBER("account_number"),
    CREDIT_CARD("credit_card");

    public final String v;

    someAccountType(String value) {
        this.v = value;
    }
}

@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Entity
@Builder
@Setter
public class SomeDetail {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name="accountType")
    private Enum.someAccountType accountType;
    ..
}
```

Repository -

```
@Repository
public interface SomeDetailRepository extends JpaRepository<SomeDetail, Long> {

    List<someDetail> findByEncryptedIfscAndEncryptedAccountNoAndAccountTypeAndIsValid(
            String encryptedIfsc, String encryptedAccountNo, String accountType, Boolean isValid);
```

Service call -

```
List<SomeDetail> someDetails = someDetailRepository.findByEncryptedIfscAndEncryptedAccountNoAndAccountTypeAndIsValid(
                ben.getEncryptedIfsc(), ben.getEncryptedAccountNo(), Enum.someAccountType.CREDIT_CARD.v, isValid);
```

Exception -

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [credit_card] did not match expected type [Enum$someAccountType (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [credit_card] did not match expected type [Enum$someAccountType (n/a)]
```

Why is it throwing this exception? I have defined @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) so it should expect string type stored in db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Enum with JPA, you need to rely on the Enum object, not on its attribute.
For instance, I'll change your repository method like this:

```
@Repository
public interface SomeDetailRepository extends JpaRepository<SomeDetail, Long> {

    List<someDetail> findByEncryptedIfscAndEncryptedAccountNoAndAccountTypeAndIsValid(
            String encryptedIfsc, String encryptedAccountNo, Enum.someAccountType accountType, Boolean isValid);
```

And use the enum val directly:

```
List<SomeDetail> someDetails = someDetailRepository.findByEncryptedIfscAndEncryptedAccountNoAndAccountTypeAndIsValid(
                ben.getEncryptedIfsc(), ben.getEncryptedAccountNo(), Enum.someAccountType.CREDIT_CARD, isValid);
```

By the way, in Java, always name your class, enum ... with a capital letter `someAccountType` -> `SomeAccountType`

### What means @Enumarated

`@Enumerated` lets you specify how Hibernate will store the value in DB. You have two options (from the javadoc):

- EnumType.ORDINAL: Persist enumerated type property or field as an integer
- EnumType.STRING: Persist enumerated type property or field as a string

But it doesn't change how you use it in your repository code, it is changing only how Hibernate will store it.